# "Object of" vs. "subject of" -- which one is correct? Does it depend on context?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammar, differences

What, exactly, is the difference between the following two sentences? Are they both correct -- or is one considered more correct in certain contexts or constructions?

1. > Jim's wailing child was the **subject of** much scrutiny.
2. > Jim's wailing child was the **object of** much scrutiny.

Each of these usages is ubiquitous, and it's not uncommon to see both within the span of a few sentences. (For example, Google estimates over 60,000 results for *"subject of study" "object of study"*.)

The difficulty seems to be that both words have several senses, and they are somewhat overlapping in this case. As a lover of grammar, I am frustrated that I cannot resolve this question in my mind.

<sub>(I tried to search to see if this question had already been asked, but I could not find it amongst the many questions concerning pronoun declension and objects and subjects as parts of speech.)</sub>

Comment: They're both perfectly valid English (though *subject* is far more common in this exact context), and obviously the meaning is essentially equivalent. Grammatically, a *subject* usually **does** something **to** an *object*, so by analogy Jim's wailing child can be an *object* just as much as a *subject*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're both grammatically correct and accepted.

For me though, and if you would like to dissect the nuance between them,

Both of them mean a "person to whom thought or action is directed"

But [object](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/object) emphasizes:

> "a person **seen** as a focus for feelings, thought etc."
>
> ex. an object of affection/ contempt

While [subject](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/subject):

> "one who experiences or is **subjected** to something"
>
> ex. the helpless subject of their cruelty/ ridicule

Answer (score 3):

In OP's exact context *(much scrutiny)*, it's not really possible to rationalise any difference in meaning. Both forms occur, but [subject](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22verb%20inflections%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22the%20subject%20of%20much%20scrutiny%22&oq=%22the%20subject%20of%20much%20scrutiny%22&gs_l=serp.3...4031.5839.11.6574.5.0.5.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0.7SIl-0A15Xg&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=47b5e442138a7ed1&biw=1300&bih=888) is about 8 times more common than [object](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22verb%20inflections%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22the%20object%20of%20much%20scrutiny%22&oq=%22the%20object%20of%20much%20scrutiny%22&gs_l=serp.3...55121.56927.12.57295.5.5.0.0.0.0.65.270.5.5.0...0.0.J5t96CvhEhg&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=47b5e442138a7ed1&biw=1300&bih=888). I don't see either as more "correct" than the other.

In the closely-related *of much debate*, that preference equally strong (and has far more examples in Google Books). I suppose a punctilious person might argue that [subject](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22verb%20inflections%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22the%20subject%20of%20much%20debate%22&oq=%22the%20subject%20of%20much%20debate%22&gs_l=serp.3...163920.171151.13.171551.19.0.19.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0.gn-AObaGC0M&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=47b5e442138a7ed1&biw=1300&bih=888) implies "topic", and [object](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22verb%20inflections%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22the%20object%20of%20much%20debate%22&oq=%22the%20object%20of%20much%20debate%22&gs_l=serp.3...57809.59593.14.60648.5.0.5.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0.KSgDBfI19BU&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=47b5e442138a7ed1&biw=1300&bih=888) implies "purpose", but I think that's clutching at straws.

In short, the meaning nets down to the same thing regardless of which word you use - Jim's wailing child can be *subjected* to scrutiny, in which case he's the *subject*. Or he can be the *object* being scrutinised, if you want to look at it that way (and if you want to adopt a minority position).

Answer (score 2):

The *subject* of the meeting is what you talk about in the meeting.  The *object* of the meeting (perhaps a better word would be objective) is the expected result of the meeting (such as a marketing strategy, etc.)

Comment: Hi, welcome to English Language & Usage Stack Exchange. Try to tailor your answer more to the question, while what you have written is correct and demonstrates a contextual difference, it doesn't really help answer the original query.

Comment: True, but this isn't totally germane to OP's situation.